# Can't initialize Google Maps in Swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

i'm trying to use google maps in my app,  i followed there main steps here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios
the sceene was loaded, but the map is empty, and i got this error :

> ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x7fd8ab5e9680 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd8b0201c40 "The network connection was lost.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.

anyone knows what's the problem ?

Comment: Based on the error message you lost network connection.

Comment: so the problem from the internet connection?
i tried there main Demo, and it's worked, so that's why i didn't understand the problem ?
first i thought it's API KEY problem.

Comment: If you get network errors in simulator that coudd be because while it was still open you changed wifi, then to reset the network connection for the simulator you can just restard it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reseting the iOS simulator:

```
iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings
```